# Why do some questions in search results don't show number of answers?

Tags: support, search

I have noticed that in the results that show up on any search on Stack Overflow, some question results, unlike many other ones, show the number of question upvotes they have received, but not the number of answers and whether an answer is accepted or not (the green mark).

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download+html

All results show both the upvotes as well as the number of answers

[image: Image 1]

And these are results that do not show number of answers:

[image: Image 2]

What causes the number of answers to be hidden?

Comment: Without links to the questions in question we can't really investigate.

Comment: It links to a post that is an answer, not a question.  Only questions have answers.  Note the Q or A that starts the post title.  If you only want to search questions then use `is:question` in the search query.

Comment: @Hans or just is:q if you want to save some typing.

Comment: Because those are answer posts, not questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic search (like https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download+html) shows mix of questions and answers (Note the Q or A that starts the post title). Answers naturally don't have answers of they own (SO is not a forum and we don't have threads following every post) and hence show no "answers count".

If you are looking for just questions add `is:q` (or `is:question`) to the query:
      https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=download%20html%20is:q

---

<sub>Answer is combined from comments by: [Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant),[Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/Jon-Clements), [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)</sub>